# Active voice with Intransitive verbs?

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity, active-voice

Is the relationship between Active and Passive voice mutually exclusive? 
A sentence not being in Passive must be assumed as a sentence in Active voice?

I'm having a little bit of trouble with this kind of exercises, like for example:

> Identify whether this sentence is in **active** or **passive** voice:
>
> *1. He arrived at his hotel at 4:30 pm.*

**I know this isn't in Passive voice, so is it correct to assume it is in Active voice?**

Theorethically this verb "Arrive" is intransitive and doesn't require a direct object for it t make sense. The doer of the action (subject) is "He".

Comment: Right...I know the theory. However the theoric material I have access to (books, internet,etc)  doesn't specify if the relationship between Active and Passive voice is mutually exclusive....That's my doubt.

Comment: The passive is formed with transitive verbs only. An intransitive verb cannot be involved in a passive construction. Some verbs can be used in both transitive and intransitive constructions.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Not quite: there are prepositional passives like "This bed has been slept in".

Comment: See also the tag for ["middle voice"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-voice).

Comment: You might want to wait a day or two before accepting an answer. For why this is usually wise, even when you get a good answer right away, see [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, if we want to really muddy the waters.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The waters are muddy on their own, without our interference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passive voice in English is generally formed from a "be" verb (am, is, were, etc.) and the past participle. Your verb "arrived" has no "be" verb and so it is not the passive voice.

It is, if fact, the simple past tense, in the active voice. The past tense of the verb "arrive" is the same as the past participle. But this verb doesn't have an auxiliary verb (e.g. "have" arrived) and so it is a simple tense.

In the passive voice, the grammatical subject is the object of the action, so verbs that have no object cannot be put into the passive.

Comment: Right! Thanks! But is the relationship between Active and Passive voice mutually exclusive? Is it correct to assume it is in Active voice? (because it isn't Passive) Or is it the case this sentence is neither of them because of the lack of an aux verb and a direct object?

Comment: @JoseLuisPachecoBoscán There are only two voices in English, so a clause must be either one or the other. If it isn't passive, it's active, and vice versa.

Comment: Tysm to you and to everyone who replied! I needed to hear something like that, maybe it was my fault because I couldn't express my doubt directly.

Comment: @JoseLuisPachecoBoscán You're welcome. One other thing: in English, _doubt_ and _question_ don't mean the same thing. The noun _Doubt_ means a lack of confidence or belief in something. The noun _Question_ means an interrogatory, a request for an answer.

Comment: @JoseLuisPachecoBoscán This is a good answer. But be careful, not all passives need a BE and past participle. [Further reading](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922). It's not your fault, btw. :)

Comment: It's not *quite* true that only transitive verbs can be passivized: the oblique of a preposition phrase complement may be cast as passive subject if the semantics allow the oblique to be understood as Patient of the action: in some sense 'affected' by it. For instance: "This bed has been slept in."

Comment: @StoneyB I learned that the prepostional passive is possible only when the subject 'changes in state'. Like "the bed was slept in" or "the chair was sat on." But what about "he was laugh at"? How does "he" change in state?

Comment: Entering the state of being an object of derision would undoubtedly affect him.

Comment: @user178049 Rules, schmules!